# What's wrong with my USB port?

Tags: usb-drive

One side USB slot on my laptop is not always allowing data connection, but seems to reliably provide power to things plugged into it. The other side USB provides power and data connection to the laptop.

Find below the `dmesg` output when I plug it in.

Any ideas on what is wrong, or next steps to troubleshoot?

[image: dmesg output]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338682/is-it-possible-to-disable-usb-port-with-known-physical-location

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - Sorry, you are suggesting that instead of my request to help fix the USB port, that I disable it?

Comment: It's a HW failure, you can only try to disable it in software to stop the torrent of errors. I'm not suggesting anything - if you wanna get it fixed for good, you'll need to take it to the service center or replace it yourself (which will most likely involve soldering) if you're brave enough.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Replying with a link, no words to accompany to frame it otherwise, was taken as a suggestion. I am comfortable with soldering, though how you can you (presumably) tell it is the connection from board to the socket, and not a controller, or some other part of the USB subsystem (PC is out of warranty)?

Comment: In my limited experience these errors indicate an issue with the USB connector which mustn't be too difficult to replace but finding a spare part could be difficult. Disabling it in software sounds like an easier fix. I'm not an expert in USB or Linux, so I might be totally wrong about everything. Suit yourself. You can as well ask on https://superuser.com/ or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/